# Compare dynamic value with Comma separated attibute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Please suggest how can I compare page Url Value inside all anchors element using Jquery.

<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="button" module="Users" page-actions="user/edit,user/create,user/list" href="user/index">User</a>
    <a class="button" module="Users" page-actions="" href="user/Demo">Demo</a>
    <a class="button" module="" page-actions="" href="/">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
```

Suppose my page Url is user/edit I want to access the element where page-actions attribute is equal to the page Url.

Comment: `$('a[page-actions*="user/edit"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `filter()` and parse the page actions to array and compare to the `window.location.pathname`

```js
/** for demo only since demo url doesn't match */
var pageUrl ='http://example.com/user/edit';
var pagePath = new URL(pageUrl).pathname;


$('.sidebar a[page-actions]').filter(function(){
   var actionArray = $(this).attr('page-actions').split(',');  
   return actionArray.includes( pagePath.slice(1));
   // on live site use:
   // return actionArray.includes('/' + location.pathname.slice(1));   

}).css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="button" module="Users" page-actions="user/edit,user/create,user/list" href="user/index">User</a>
    <a class="button" module="Users" page-actions="" href="user/Demo">Demo</a>
    <a class="button" module="" page-actions="" href="/">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
```